# Another Invalid top-level type in JSON write crash

Tags: ios, swift5, nsjsonserialization, jsonencoder

So, Xcode 13.1, iOS 15.0, I am stuck with this JSON serialization for a rather important project which has to be delivered yesterday(!) as usual, and instead crashes.

This is the piece of code I'm dealing with:

```
var jsonData: Data
    do {
        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: roomBookings, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
        return false
    }
```

This is the object I am trying to JSON serialize:

```
Rooms.RoomBookings(
bookings: [Rooms.RoomBooking(
bookingID: "23EB86CB-A918-47D4-ADDB-346DBB4E3471",
 roomID: "BgX86SbN0UifijkwU8HZ", 
isAllDay: false, 
startTimestamp: 1636440856861, 
endTimestamp: 1636444456861, 
user: "trialUser")
])
```

This is the error I keep getting, which makes the app crash (of course we can avoid the actual crash checking with isValidJSONObject, but that's not the point here).

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]:
 Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

Here below is the model, The error is focused on the top-level type, what's wrong with that? It's just an *Array* of *RoooBooking* instances, conformed with *Codable*, so what?

Someone knows what am I doing wrong? That would be greatly appreciated!

```
// MARK: - RoomBookings
struct RoomBookings: Codable {
    var bookings: [RoomBooking]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bookings = "bookings"
    }
}

// MARK: RoomBookings convenience initializers and mutators
extension RoomBookings {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try newJSONDecoder().decode(RoomBookings.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    init(fromURL url: URL) throws {
        try self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    }

    func with(
        bookings: [RoomBooking]? = nil
    ) -> RoomBookings {
        return RoomBookings(
            bookings: bookings ?? self.bookings
        )
    }

    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try newJSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}

// MARK: - RoomBooking
struct RoomBooking: Codable {
    var bookingID: String
    var roomID: String
    var isAllDay: Bool
    var startTimestamp: Int
    var endTimestamp: Int
    var user: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bookingID = "bookingId"
        case roomID = "roomId"
        case isAllDay = "isAllDay"
        case startTimestamp = "startTimestamp"
        case endTimestamp = "endTimestamp"
        case user = "user"
    }
}

// MARK: RoomBooking convenience initializers and mutators

extension RoomBooking {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try newJSONDecoder().decode(RoomBooking.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    init(fromURL url: URL) throws {
        try self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    }

    func with(
        bookingID: String? = nil,
        roomID: String? = nil,
        isAllDay: Bool? = nil,
        startTimestamp: Int? = nil,
        endTimestamp: Int? = nil,
        user: String? = nil
    ) -> RoomBooking {
        return RoomBooking(
            bookingID: bookingID ?? self.bookingID,
            roomID: roomID ?? self.roomID,
            isAllDay: isAllDay ?? self.isAllDay,
            startTimestamp: startTimestamp ?? self.startTimestamp,
            endTimestamp: endTimestamp ?? self.endTimestamp,
            user: user ?? self.user
        )
    }

    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try newJSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}

// MARK: - Helper functions for creating encoders and decoders

func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}

func newJSONEncoder() -> JSONEncoder {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return encoder
}
```

Comment: why not simply use `try JSONEncoder().encode(roomBookings)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    var jsonData: Data
    do {
        jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(roomBookings)
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!) //to check the actual O/P am adding it here, remove it from your code
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
        return false
    }
```

**O/P:**

> {     "bookings": [{      "endTimestamp": 1,      "roomId": "1",      "user":
> "abcd",       "isAllDay": true,       "bookingId": "1",       "startTimestamp": 1
> }] }

Comment: @fabrizio-prosperi: Am glad I could help :)